# Visual Basic Finding Multiples of Four

Tags: visual-studio, basic

I am currently in college doing Computer Science and have been set some tasks for programming. I am very new at VB so allot of the code I've written so far is very basic.

They project I need to do now is to output a day month and year when the user types in numbers equivalent. So for example:

A user types in:
1 12 2016

Would display as:
1st of December 2016.

I've worked through most of it but I'm stuck now. I need to add in considerations for leap years, so that if someone types in 29 2 2016 then it will be allowed, whereas if it's 29 2 2015 it wont. The code that I have now has a checkbox that allows the user to tick if it is a leap year and untick if it isn't. Is there an easy way to input leap years without putting all of them? (Like 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012...).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far, do you have a solution, even one that does not work - post the code to help the community help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll post the code asap tomorrow when I retrieve my Pen drive from college, thanks.

Comment: You are not looking at the big picture.  This is not different from the user typing 32 12 2016.  The .NET framework has a way to store dates, the DateTime type.  It knows how to tell you that a date is not valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with Visual Basic, as I said I'm an absolute beginner so i don't know how to use the DateTime type yet. I apologize if I should, but there's always room to learn :). Ill post my code tomorrow (you can poke fun at how shitty it is if you wish!) and maybe you could help me improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured the problem out, but thanks for the help, this is my code so far (sorry ts fairly basic).

Public Class formDayMonthYear

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    'Calculates the Day, Month and Year in text according to the users input of numbers

    'Variables
    Dim iDay As Integer = txtDay.Text
    Dim iMonth As Integer = txtMonth.Text
    Dim iYear As Integer = txtYear.Text
    Dim sDay As String
    Dim sMonth As String
    Dim sYear As String
```

'MISSING CHECKBOX PART

```
    If iMonth = 2 Then
        If iDay > 28 Then
            MsgBox(iDay & " is an incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
        End If
    End If

    'Otherwise if it is ticked
    Else

    If iMonth = 2 Then
        If iDay > 29 Then
            MsgBox(iDay & " is a incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
        End If
    End If
    End If

    If iMonth = 4 Or iMonth = 6 Or iMonth = 9 Or iMonth = 11 Then
        If iDay <= 0 Or iDay >= 31 Then
            MsgBox(iDay & " is an incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
        End If

    ElseIf iMonth = 1 Or iMonth = 2 Or iMonth = 3 Or iMonth = 5 Or iMonth = 7 Or iMonth = 8 Or iMonth = 10 Or iMonth = 12 Then
        If iDay <= 0 Or iDay >= 32 Then
            MsgBox(iDay & " is an incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")

        End If

        If iDay = 1 Or iDay = 21 Or iDay = 31 Then
            sDay = iDay & "st"

        ElseIf iDay = 2 Or iDay = 22 Then
            sDay = iDay & "nd"

        ElseIf iDay = 3 Or iDay = 23 Then
            sDay = iDay & "rd"

        Else : sDay = iDay & "th"
        End If

        If iMonth = 1 Then
            sMonth = "January"
        ElseIf iMonth = 2 Then
            sMonth = "February"
        ElseIf iMonth = 3 Then
            sMonth = "March"
        ElseIf iMonth = 4 Then
            sMonth = "April"
        ElseIf iMonth = 5 Then
            sMonth = "May"
        ElseIf iMonth = 6 Then
            sMonth = "June"
        ElseIf iMonth = 7 Then
            sMonth = "July"
        ElseIf iMonth = 8 Then
            sMonth = "August"
        ElseIf iMonth = 9 Then
            sMonth = "September"
        ElseIf iMonth = 10 Then
            sMonth = "October"
        ElseIf iMonth = 11 Then
            sMonth = "November"
        ElseIf iMonth = 12 Then
            sMonth = "December"
        Else
            MsgBox(iMonth & " doesn't exist as a month!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        End If

        sYear = iYear

        txtDecision.Text = sDay & " of " & sMonth & " " & sYear
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

But as someone suggested before they deleted it, I can work it out using MOD, like this:

If iYear mod 4 = 0 then
   'Code to say is a leap year
   Else
   'Code to say isn't leap year
End If

So my new snippet of code is:

'If the remainder of Years / 4 = 0 then

If iYear Mod 4 = 0 Then

```
        'If the month is 2 (February) then
        If iMonth = 2 Then
            If iDay > 29 Then
                MsgBox(iDay & " is an incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
            End If
        End If

        'Otherwise if it is ticked
    Else

        If iMonth = 2 Then
            If iDay > 28 Then
                MsgBox(iDay & " is a incorrect day!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error!")
            End If
        End If
    End If
```